# C++: Fetch_add on memory mapped file

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-mapped-files

i openend a file using the boost mapped-file library.
Is it possible to use a "fetch_add" (value is read at certain position then added with another and written back to that very same position atomically) on this mapped file?

If multiple threads write to it in parallel there could be problems without atomicity involved

The file is in binary format and contains ints or doubles (depends on specific file).

I also tried locks/mutexes but they always slow my program down when using multiple threads. The time spent in the locked regions is just to big compared to the rest of the algorithm and the threads block each other.

Are there any better ways so that multiple threads can write to a mapped file with high performance?

Thanks.
Laz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there multiple processes mapping this file, or just multiple threads?

If multiple processes are accessing this memory mapped file concurrently, you'll have to do your own (inter-process) synchronization.

If it's only multiple threads, then you can atomically update the memory the same way you'd do it for any other word of memory, with the caveat that you can't use `std::atomic` (because obviously the bytes correspond directly to a section in the file, and not to `std::atomic` structures).
So, you must resort to using your specific platform's support for atomically modifying memory, namely `lock xadd` on x86 via, e.g., [`InterlockedIncrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx) on Win32 (or [`__sync_fetch_and_add`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp121.bg.doc%2Fcompiler_ref%2Fbif_gcc_atomic_fetch_add.html) with g++). Be careful to ensure the memory ordering semantics (and return value!) are as you expect.

Wrapping the platform-specific functions in a platform-independent way (if you need that) can be a bit of a hassle, though, and so in that case I'd suggest keeping the concurrently-accessed data in separate `std::atomic` variables, then updating the corresponding file bytes just once at the end.

Note that all of this is orthogonal to memory mapping -- the OS backs the memory-mapped file with pages that it swaps in and out on demand, and the memory management unit that manages those pages is the same as the one that handles arbitrary other (non-mapped) pages, hence the pages themselves can be modified by multiple threads without having to worry about anything other than the usual (application-level) data races.

Comment: There are just multiple threads accessing the mapping. So std::atomic is just for single values and there is no way to make a block of memory atomic, like an array for example? Except to make every element itself an atomic single value? Not considering platform specifics. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: virtual +1 for __sync_fetch_and_add! Too low rep still :-(

Comment: @Lazarus535: `std::atomic` is a template, so in theory you can have an atomic variable of any type, including an array or a large structure. However, [only certain specializations are lock-free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) (ideally all the ones the hardware supports, given an efficient implementation of the standard library), and atomicity is achieved through a normal mutex (internal to the implementation) for all the other types. Note also that an array of atomic variables is not at all the same as an atomic variable containing an array :-)

Comment: The atomic variable containing an array would default to the mutex in case of a container (vector, etc) or be useless in case of a pointer to an array (fetch and add whise). Thanks! This has been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Since a memory mapped file behaves like ordinary memory [1], it will work just as well as on any other piece of memory.

This compiles (in using `clang++3.6 -Wall -Wextra`), but is technically undefined (because `std::atomic<T>` is not guaranteed to be the same type or have the same alignment rules as `T`):

```
   std::atomic<uint64_t> *p; 
   p = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<uint64_t>*>(&dest[index]);
   p->fetch_add(value);
```

This should be good in g++ and clang++:

```
   dest[index] = __sync_fetch_and_add(&dest[index], value);
```

(Both generate nearly identical assembler code, - the latter uses `xaddq` [which returns the original value], where the former uses `addq` - usign `__sync_add_and_fetch` would do the same `addq`, I expect)

[1] Because it IS ordinary memory - the mapping mechanism in Linux is exactly the same mechanism that handles ordinary memory, such as swapping data in/out when your there isn't enough memory available, or if you use code/data in an application that just started. Although I don't have access to Windows source code, I believe this is true there too. Other OS's may well implement it in a subtly different way, but there's no reason to believe it will prevent atomic operations to work.

Comment: I will indeed try to cast the pointer to the std::atomic just to see if it works. Seems very nasty to me :-) Thanks.

Comment: Just bear in mind that there is no guarantee that this won't break at some point in future - or if you compile for a different processor, etc.